# What does this view function do in Python using Flask framework?

Tags: python, flask

```
class NameForm(FlaskForm):
    name=StringField('What is your name?', validators=[Required()])
    submit=SubmitField('Submit')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form=NameForm()
    # print(form.name.data)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['name']=form.name.data
        # form.name.data=''
        # print('post')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    # print('get')
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, name=session.get('name'))
```

From what I understand, doesn't matter if I send a post or get request, the `index()` function will always run this line of code `form=NameForm()` where `form` will be assigned to a new value.

However, when I hit submit, a post request which is sent to the server takes the form data along with it, that data is remained even when `form` has been assigned to a new value at the first line of the `index()` function.

Comment: Yes, this code will create a brand new `NameForm` instance every time it is invoked - but in the case of a POST request, it will automatically be filled in with the submitted field values (by way of Flask's `request` global variable).  The code couldn't count on the original `NameForm` from the GET still being around, anyway - the server could have been restarted between the time of the GET and the POST, or the two requests could have been handled by entirely different worker threads/processes.

Comment: oh, thank you so much for your answer, I get it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every invocation of `index` will cause a new instance of `form` to be created, as you note.

I'm not sure I follow the question, so am guessing at a possible source of confusion.

Under the covers, `FlaskForm` subclasses are aware of the flask request, and will populate the instance from the request if it's a POST, PUT, PATCH, or DELETE. So when `index` does

```
form=NameForm()
```

that `form` will be empty in the case of a GET, or will contain submitted data in the case of a POST.

If you're curious how this awareness works, see https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/master/flask_wtf/form.py#L54 where `flask-wtf` overrides a method in `wtforms` to provide flask-specific behavior.